# Catalog Search Index not changing status "required index"

Tags: indexing, catalogsearch

I ran many time reindex process and system always returning the status "required index". I truncate the table without success.

Comment: System sometimes returns "There was a problem with reindexing process."

Comment: is there anything in the log files when you see this error message?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I cleaned my var/reports and rebuild with success. Now it's ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of error when rebuilding index. Go into your magento `var/report` path and clean old errors and try again.

Answer (score 1):

**Check which events set the indexes to invalid**

[Magento docs](https://docs.magento.com/m1/ee/user_guide/system-operations/index-modes.html) show the events for every index (see Events that Trigger Reindexing):

Further you can add some debug code in `Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Process::updateStatus()`

```
if ($status === Mage_Index_Model_Process::STATUS_REQUIRE_REINDEX) {
    Mage::log(sprintf('Indexer %s was invalidated.', $process->getIndexer()->getName()), null, 'invalid_index.log', true);
    foreach (debug_backtrace() as $db) {
        Mage::log(sprintf('%s::%s', $db['class'], $db['function']), null, 'invalid_index.log', true);
    }
}
```

This should show you a stack trace about what is setting the indexes to invalid. In my case it were API requests of 'catalogProductUpdate'

You can also check the exception.log if you'll find any locks of the 'index_process' table. This tables holds the data you see in System > Index Management

Creds for the debug code go [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/89582/6291)