# SOLVED - Index Management "Catalog Search Index" Broken

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0, catalogsearch, reindex

I was trying some exetension, but after I installed "Ajax Search by LitExtension", my search index is broken.

Catalog Search Index says "Reindex Required". So I did.

[image]

Then I get this error. I cannot reindex it and also error message is somehow empty.
[image]

I deleted var/report as suggested here :

[Catalog Search Index not changing status "required index"](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8888/catalog-search-index-not-changing-status-required-index)

but no luck.

How can I fix this?
I use magento 1.8.1.0 .

Comment: what is the error? its not visible in screenshot

Comment: It is not visible for me as well.
Error is appearing but it is empty.

Comment: try uninstalling the Ajax search extension reindex and check if that is causing an error

Comment: I uninstalled. But no luck. Still appearing.

Comment: Have you tried to start the reindex from console?

Comment: Please clear var/locks folder...

Comment: I cleaned var/locks folder, same, still error.

I tried reindex using SSH with this 

php shell/indexer.php reindexall

, then I got 

PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getReadConnection() on a non-object                                                                         in    /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Co                                                                        llection/Abstract.php on line 134

Comment: and 

Fatal error: Call to a member function getReadConnection() on a non-object in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collect                                                                        ion/Abstract.php on line 134

Comment: and now site is down...

Comment: Check your core_config_data table for traces of the module you removed. It may still be trying to initialize it there, by what you are saying it sounds like the module has a resource collection. Also always make a database backup when adding or removing modules. You may also want to remove the module's tables. Those table names can be found in the module sql/ installer file

Comment: Thank you DWils! Site is back again after deleting traces of the above extension.

However, search index is still not working.

Comment: I tried again with ssh to reindex catalogsearch_fulltext, but the result was empty line.

Comment: I solved this issue by changing Attribute to "Searchable" >> "No". In my case, to change tax_class_id did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by changing Attribute to "Searchable" >> "No". In my case, to change tax_class_id did the trick.