# mass_action index process

Tags: magento-1.9, indexing, magento-community, massaction

We are having the problem that the mass_action index process never seems to execute. This has the side effect that the job data of this job grows substantially over time.

In our case over the course of several days the job data grows to several MB.

```
mysql> select type, entity, count(*), avg(length(new_data)), max(length(new_data)) from index_event group by type, entity;
+-----------------------+--------------------------------+----------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
| type                  | entity                         | count(*) | avg(length(new_data)) | max(length(new_data)) |
+-----------------------+--------------------------------+----------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
| catalog_reindex_price | catalog_product                |     1368 |              442.7982 |                   443 |
| mass_action           | catalog_product                |        1 |          6176981.0000 |               6176981 |
| save                  | awaffiliate_withdrawal_request |        6 |              444.3333 |                   445 |
| save                  | cataloginventory_stock_item    |     4439 |              607.9685 |                   608 |
| save                  | catalog_category               |       71 |             1040.3662 |                  3395 |
| save                  | catalog_eav_attribute          |        3 |              424.6667 |                   476 |
| save                  | catalog_product                |     1368 |             1269.0899 |                  1922 |
+-----------------------+--------------------------------+----------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
```

As this data is unserialized and then serialized for an update as well as transfered from and to the DB server an update to the mass_action entry takes currently around 3s to complete. This affects code that triggers an update of this index.

As I understand it the triggering an update of the following indexes will update mass action

```
mysql> select ip.indexer_code, ipe.process_id, ipe.event_id, ipe.status, ie.type, ie.created_at from index_process_event as ipe left join index_event as ie on ipe.event_id = ie.event_id  left join index_process as ip on ip.process_id = ipe.process_id where ie.type  = 'mass_action';
+---------------------------+------------+----------+--------+-------------+---------------------+
| indexer_code              | process_id | event_id | status | type        | created_at          |
+---------------------------+------------+----------+--------+-------------+---------------------+
| catalog_product_attribute |          1 |     9074 | new    | mass_action | 2016-11-03 23:18:06 |
| catalog_product_price     |          2 |     9074 | new    | mass_action | 2016-11-03 23:18:06 |
| catalogsearch_fulltext    |          7 |     9074 | new    | mass_action | 2016-11-03 23:18:06 |
| cataloginventory_stock    |          8 |     9074 | new    | mass_action | 2016-11-03 23:18:06 |
| tag_summary               |          9 |     9074 | new    | mass_action | 2016-11-03 23:18:06 |
| catalog_product_flat      |         19 |     9074 | new    | mass_action | 2016-11-03 23:18:06 |
| catalog_category_product  |         21 |     9074 | new    | mass_action | 2016-11-03 23:18:06 |
+---------------------------+------------+----------+--------+-------------+---------------------+
```

We have all indexes set to manual and run cronjobs at various times of the day to update the indexes.

```
mysql> select * from index_process;
+------------+-------------------------------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------+
| process_id | indexer_code                  | status          | started_at          | ended_at            | mode   |
+------------+-------------------------------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------+
|          1 | catalog_product_attribute     | require_reindex | 2016-11-15 00:40:10 | 2016-11-15 00:10:24 | manual |
|          2 | catalog_product_price         | require_reindex | 2016-11-15 00:45:09 | 2016-11-15 00:15:44 | manual |
|          7 | catalogsearch_fulltext        | require_reindex | 2016-11-14 23:51:23 | 2016-11-14 12:12:30 | manual |
|          8 | cataloginventory_stock        | require_reindex | 2016-11-15 00:47:01 | 2016-11-15 00:45:09 | manual |
|          9 | tag_summary                   | require_reindex | 2016-11-14 23:54:01 | 2016-11-14 23:54:01 | manual |
|         12 | awaffiliate_affiliate_balance | pending         | 2016-11-14 23:54:01 | 2016-11-14 23:54:03 | manual |
|         18 | catalog_url                   | require_reindex | 2016-11-14 23:54:03 | 2016-11-14 21:02:53 | manual |
|         19 | catalog_product_flat          | require_reindex | 2016-11-15 00:49:02 | 2016-11-15 00:10:10 | manual |
|         20 | catalog_category_flat         | pending         | 2016-11-15 00:51:01 | 2016-11-15 00:51:04 | manual |
|         21 | catalog_category_product      | require_reindex | 2016-11-15 00:53:01 | 2016-11-15 00:06:04 | manual |
|         22 | ampgrid_qty_sold              | require_reindex | 2016-11-15 00:06:04 | 2016-11-14 12:21:18 | manual |
+------------+-------------------------------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------+
```

Re-index cron schedule:

```
0-59/15 *  *   *   *  cd html && /usr/bin/php  /www/sites/files/html/shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_price > /dev/null 2>&1
2-59/15 *  *   *   *  cd html && /usr/bin/php  /www/sites/files/html/shell/indexer.php --reindex cataloginventory_stock > /dev/null 2>&1
4-59/15 *  *   *   *  cd html && /usr/bin/php  /www/sites/files/html/shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_flat > /dev/null 2>&1
6-59/15 *  *   *   *  cd html && /usr/bin/php  /www/sites/files/html/shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_flat > /dev/null 2>&1
8-59/15 *  *   *   *  cd html && /usr/bin/php  /www/sites/files/html/shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_product > /dev/null 2>&1
10-59/15 *  *   *   *  cd html && /usr/bin/php  /www/sites/files/html/shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_attribute > /dev/null 2>&1

10 4  *   *   *    cd html && /usr/bin/php  /www/sites/files/html/shell/indexer.php --reindex catalogsearch_fulltext > /dev/null 2>&1
20 4  *   *   *    cd html && /usr/bin/php  /www/sites/files/html/shell/indexer.php --reindex ampgrid_qty_sold > /dev/null 2>&1
30 4  *   *   *    cd html && /usr/bin/php  /www/sites/files/html/shell/indexer.php --reindex awaffiliate_affiliate_balance > /dev/null 2>&1
40 4  *   *   *    cd html && /usr/bin/php  /www/sites/files/html/shell/indexer.php --reindex tag_summary > /dev/null 2>&1

50  */6   *   *  *  cd html && /usr/bin/php  /www/sites/files/html/shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_url > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Index timings:

```
$ time php shell/indexer.php --reindexall
Product Attributes index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:21
Product Prices index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:32
Search Index index was rebuilt successfully in 00:02:31
Stock Status index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Tag Aggregation Data index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Affiliates Balance index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:02
Catalog URL Rewrites index was rebuilt successfully in 00:10:08
Product Flat Data index was rebuilt successfully in 00:01:54
Category Flat Data index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:04
Category Products index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:18
Qty Sold index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:15

real    16m9.562s
user    8m23.551s
sys     0m19.705s
```

My assumption is that running a full re-index would process the mass_action process and clear it out of the table. Unfortunately this is not the case. Does anyone know what the conditions are that clear out that process?

Comment: I'm experiencing this too. The 'mass_action' row in the table keeps growing and growing, despite indexes running successfully. I truncated the `index_event` table and the `index_process` table and then ran a script to update stock item figures. The row re-appeared, smaller than before of course, and kept growing again after a reindex.

Comment: I've never found a proper solution for that. What I ended up doing was adding a cron job that deletes out  mass_action frequently. It should have no side effect as long as you manually index all indexes frequently.

Answer (score 1):

Did you notice the indexation time on some of your indexes? It varies from seconds to mostly hours. Depending on how you configured your cronjobs, your store might be busy indexing all day, continously. This could be your problem as it's not able to finish the indexations or at least keep up with it. Having a locked index at all times could cause some trouble and is known for these type of issues.

I have to make some assumtpions here, correct me if needeed. Specify some more information on your setup if you think this might be related to your problem. I have been working on a project that should help developers clean out their `core_url_rewrite` table because it grows substantially over time in certain scenario's. I think yours is having this problem too since it ran for almost 3 hours, and the issue you describe could be related to it. I see similair things at test cases.

Is your problem specific to just the `mass_action` event object? or does it happen with the other event types as well? (save, delete, reindex etc.  (Mage_Index_Model_Event)). If not, I would say it's related to the indexes not being indexed properly. Given the fact there could be locks on tables, that are required for processing, i'm not sure of this. You could easily check for active locks using something like:

```
 $indexes = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessesCollection()->load();
    foreach($indexes as $index){
        if($index->isLocked(){
            echo "Index" . $index->getIndexerCode() . " with state " . $index->getStatus() . " is locked since " . $index->getStartedAt() . "!";
        }
    }
```

Or use my gist, don't forget to remove it when your done. It's not for production usage.

[One-page index & lock status overview](https://gist.github.com/frosit/f017bf37cb6ce023a5923255dbcee888)

So i think that when you fix your index times, your problem might go away and the store could run way more smoothly. In the case of the `core_url_rewrite` table, the overhead is generated by Magento itself in an effort to have unique URL's but ends up duplicating them. This has complications on the SEO and performance side. The solution to this problem is making the URL's unique and clearing out all the overhead, without damaging your SEO scores. When they're clean, you'll notice a big difference in index times. Some of my cases started generating sitemaps again after months.

Cleaning it can be tricky but the magerun bundle I put together from scripts I used can help you with at least the rewrite table. Currently it's a proof of concept, so make sure to have backups. When it's proven something useful I will rebuild it.

[Magerun bundle with commands for cleaning core_url_rewrite](https://github.com/frosit/magerun-rewritetoolset)

As for the other tables, I have to assume that there's something similar causing overhead since i have no other info from which i can relate an issue. Maybe you could add some more info on things like the size of your catalog, server specs, store scope configurations, they are all related to your index performance. You might also want to check your table to make sure it's not missing constraints etc.

[Magento DB Repair](http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/magento/database-repair-tool.html)

There's one stack post containing a great collection of information on Magento's indexes, just in case you haven't seen it already.

[Stack post on indexes](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/89579/when-are-the-indexes-invalidated)

I hope this is of any value to you, good luck

Comment: Very interesting insights. I set up the cron jobs in a way that all indexes complete in a way that there is no overlap (added schedule above). The longest indexing process is the url rewrite one but that finishes in around 10 minutes. I checked the index locks and when no index job is running none of the indexes are locked. I'm not sure how the indexing times in the index_process table work but started_at and ended_at sometimes don't seem to reflect the same cron job. It looks like started_at might get updated when the require_reindex flag is set.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still have this problem but it has to do with you running in MANUAL mode for all your indexers.

In Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Event you have a _beforeSave that does the following:

```
/**
 * Check if semilar event exist before start saving data
 *
 * @param Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $object
 * @return Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Event
 */
protected function _beforeSave(Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $object)
{
    /**
     * Check if event already exist and merge previous data
     */
    if (!$object->getId()) {
        $select = $this->_getReadAdapter()->select()
            ->from($this->getMainTable())
            ->where('type=?', $object->getType())
            ->where('entity=?', $object->getEntity());
        if ($object->hasEntityPk()) {
            $select->where('entity_pk=?', $object->getEntityPk());
        }
        $data = $this->_getWriteAdapter()->fetchRow($select);
        if ($data) {
            $object->mergePreviousData($data);
        }
    }
    $object->cleanNewData();
    return parent::_beforeSave($object);
}
```

Here the $object->cleanNewData() will invoke in Mage_Index_Model_Event:

```
/**
 * Clean new data, unset data for done processes
 *
 * @return Mage_Index_Model_Event
 */
public function cleanNewData()
{
    $processIds = $this->getProcessIds();
    if (!is_array($processIds) || empty($processIds)) {
        return $this;
    }

    $newData = $this->getNewData(false);
    foreach ($processIds as $processId => $processStatus) {
        if ($processStatus == Mage_Index_Model_Process::EVENT_STATUS_DONE) {
            $process = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessById($processId);
            if ($process) {
                $namespace = get_class($process->getIndexer());
                if (array_key_exists($namespace, $newData)) {
                    unset($newData[$namespace]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $this->setNewData(serialize($newData));

    return $this;
}
```

Notice that $newData will never be reset if the Index_Process status is not equals Mage_Index_Model_Process::EVENT_STATUS_DONE? Well, in MANUAL mode for the Indexers this will never happen att Index Event Register.

This is because Mage_Index_Model_Process will never process the Event in MANUAL mode (which it shouldn't) and will therefore never set the status to Mage_Index_Model_Process::EVENT_STATUS_DONE.

```
/**
 * Process event with assigned indexer object
 *
 * @param Mage_Index_Model_Event $event
 * @return Mage_Index_Model_Process
 */
public function processEvent(Mage_Index_Model_Event $event)
{
    if (!$this->matchEvent($event)) {
        return $this;
    }
    if ($this->getMode() == self::MODE_MANUAL) {
        $this->changeStatus(self::STATUS_REQUIRE_REINDEX);
        return $this;
    }

    $this->_getResource()->updateProcessStartDate($this);
    $this->_setEventNamespace($event);
    $isError = false;

    try {
        $this->getIndexer()->processEvent($event);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $isError = true;
    }
    $event->resetData();
    $this->_resetEventNamespace($event);
    $this->_getResource()->updateProcessEndDate($this);
    $event->addProcessId($this->getId(), $isError ? self::EVENT_STATUS_ERROR : self::EVENT_STATUS_DONE);

    return $this;
}
```

If you just want to lower the size then you can either reset the event or just set the Indexers to use REAL_TIME mode and reindex all through shell/reindexer.php. The next time you make an action that creates indexing event the old data will be unset.